# Google Protobuf - missing descriptor for type registry

Tags: json, protocol-buffers

I have some Google Protobuf json with an '@type' field whose value is an URI that will tell someone the type of Protobuf message it is e.g.     `"@type": "type.googleapis.com/llcore.ModemDataAtlas"`. From my understanding, these json strings should be serialized into an 'Any' type first. whenever I do this though, I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Type registry has no descriptor for type name ''llcore.ModemMessage'
```

Here is my code:

```
string jsonString = "";
string jsonPath = @"C:\Users\user\Documents\TestRepos\ExampleProto\protoType.json";
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(jsonPath))
{
    jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();
}

Any anyProto = Any.Parser.ParseJson(msg); // Exception occurs here
```

Does anyone know how to properly deserialize into a Protobuf Any class? How do I go about creating a type registry and adding a descriptor for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First let me explain why you cannot simply parse/serialize arbitrary JSON to `Any` (or vice versa). `Any` itself has 2 fields:

- `typeUrl` - In your case `"type.googleapis.com/llcore.ModemDataAtlas"`
- `value` - The actual content encoded as a binary protobuf

A binary protobuf encodes each field as a pair of key and content, think of it like a Map. The key is not the name of the field, rather the number given to the field in the proto definition.

A JSON Object is a Map too, but it uses the field name as index. So, without any type information (Descriptor) for the type the JSON parser would not know how to map a named field of a JSON object, to a binary encoded version of it that is only identified by a number.

Just to make it clear: You cannot parse/serialize unknown types that are encoded as `Any`! Your app needs to know about them, either by statically compiling the descriptors into it or by looking up type descriptors at runtime. This is basically the point of the `TypeRegistry` to allow you to load descriptors at runtime, but you have to provide this infrastructure of looking up types yourself.

To make this work in your case, your app needs to know about the types that are packed in the `Any`. Then you can create a `TypeRegistry` and pass that to the `JsonParser` constructor. I'm not a `C#` developer, but something along the lines:

```
var registry = TypeRegistry.FromMessages(MyMessage.Descriptor);
var parser = new JsonParser(new JsonParser.Settings(20, registry));
var message =  parser.Parse<Any>(payload);
```